# ¿Cómo puedo obtener palabras de un string en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Por ejemplo, tengo esto:

> SELECT  id, name, cliente, type, status FROM campaign

Y quiero obtener solo `id`, `name`, `cliente` y `type`, pero no solo que funcione en ese string sino en cualquiera practicamente para obtener los campos de una consulta.

Comment: No se entiede lo que preguntas, reformula la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo que la entrada de la función es una consulta SQL del tipo:

```
select campo1, campo2 , campoN from ... where ...
```

puedes empezar por acotar lo que necesitas, eliminando todo desde FROM en adelante. Puesto que SQL permite tanto mayúsculas como minúsculas para las palabras reservadas del lenguaje, podrías hacer un reemplazo por cadena vacía de la siguiente expresión:

```
let trozos = consulta.replace(/ *select | from.*/ig,'');
```

Esta expresión regular significa

> Cualquier espacio (o ninguno) seguido de `select` **o** un espacio seguido de `from` y todo lo que venga detrás, ignorando si es mayúsculas o minúsculas, todas las veces que se encuentre.

Con lo que quitarías `SELECT` y `FROM ...`, quedándote sólo con los campos que buscas. Entonces sólo te queda trocear usando como separador la coma y, por si hay espacios, hacer un `trim` de cada elemento:

```js
let consulta = 'SELECT id, name, cliente, type, status FROM campaign';

function extraerCampos(consulta) {
  let campos = consulta.replace(/ *select | from.*/ig,'');
  
  return campos.split(',').map(s=>s.trim());
}

console.log(extraerCampos(consulta));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias era lo que estaba buscando

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener palabras de un `string` puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
//ejemplo de una función
function prueba() {

    let frase = 'SELECT id, name, cliente, type, status FROM campaign';    
    frase = frase.replace(/,/g, "");    
    let resultado = frase.split(" ");    
    console.log(resultado);
}
```

Primero guardamos en una variable el `string` que queramos.

```
let frase = 'SELECT id, name, cliente, type, status FROM campaign';
```

Luego quitamos todas las `,` que haya en ese `string` con una expresión regular.

```
frase = frase.replace(/,/g, "");
```

A continuación hacemos un `split` cuando haya un espacio en blanco para generar un `array`

```
let resultado = frase.split(" ");
```

Si vemos lo que tenemos en la variable `resultado`

```
0: "SELECT"
1: "id"
2: "name"
3: "cliente"
4: "type"
5: "status"
6: "FROM"
7: "campaign"
```

Ahora tan solo necesitas la variable `resultado` junto con el *indice* para sacar la palabra que quieras:

```
console.log(resultado[1]); // id
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo más habitual sería obtener la lista de campos como un array. La respuesta de @Pablo Lozano me parece perfecta.

Un método alternativo podría ser:

```
function getQueryFields(query, get_as_string=false)
{
    var begin = query.indexOf("SELECT") + ("SELECT".length);
    var end   = query.indexOf("FROM") - 1;
    var str_fields = query.substring(begin, end);


    return (get_as_string)
        ? str_fields
        : str_fields.split(',').map(str=>str.trim());
}


/**
 * Tests
 *
 */

var str = "SELECT id, name, cliente, type, status FROM campaign";
console.log(getQueryFields(str));
console.log(getQueryFields(str, true));
```

El resultado sería:

```
["id", "name", "cliente", "type", "status"]
id, name, cliente, type, status
```